# Is there any equivalent of ProxyPassReverse/ProxyPass for Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, reverse-proxy

Is there any equivalent of Apache ProxyPassReverse/ProxyPass for Jboss AS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if JBoss supports anything like this, but it doesn't seem that it should be the role of an application server to also handle all of the numerous and complex features of a dedicated HTTP server like Apache HTTP Server.

Just like it is very common to front something like Apache Tomcat with Apache HTTP Server, couldn't you do the same with JBoss?  If not, please further detail your need so that we can provide a better answer.

Comment: I'm trying to divert all openfire calls via jboss, Currently I have done it thru Apache. Openfire or ejabberd exposes this xmpp-http bind request via 7070 or 5284 port. I'm trying to pass all the traffic via 80.